# NSArray possibly causing app crash?

Tags: crash, nsarray, sprite-kit

I have a method that chooses a random sprite node from an array to place on the screen. My app is crashing though. This is a snippet from the error message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString decodeObjectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x47b4'

This is the method I have written out.

```
-(SKSpriteNode *) gamePieces {

NSArray *things = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"piece1", @"piece2", @"piece3", nil];

int r = arc4random () % [things count];

SKSpriteNode *randomObject = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithCoder:[things objectAtIndex:r]];



return randomObject;
}
```

Any ideas as to what the problem is?

Comment: You are applying "decodeObjectForKey to an NSString.  That won't work.

Comment: How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: First off, find out how to capture and interpret an exception stack trace so you can figure out where the error actually is.  Then figure out why you're calling "decodeObjectForKey" (which is the the operation that using `[]` indexing on an NSArray or NSDictionary translates to) on an NSString (which you've probably mislabeled as an NSArray or NSString).

Comment: to put it simply: you can not init a sprite with a string like "piece1". A string is not a sprite, a string can not become a sprite, a string can not be decoded into a sprite. Question is, do you have an image like piece1.png in your app bundle? If so use spriteWithImageNamed: to create the sprite. Or if you wanted the sprite to just have "piece1" as its name, create the sprite and then assign the name to sprite.name.

Comment: Thank you for your responses! I should have explained better that each sprite is more complex than just a shape etc.. I had assigned the names in each sprite and had hoped that it would call from those methods. I ended up creating a switch and assigning each sprite to a different case and returning whatever sprite node it chose.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by @HotLicks and @LearnCocos2d, `-initWithCoder:` is out of place here. Creating a new SKSpriteNode from scratch is typically done with one of the designated initializers (`+spriteNodeWithColor:size:`,`+spriteNodeWithImageNamed:` or `spriteNodeWithTexture:`). Assuming you just wish to create an SKSpriteNode with a random image, take a look at the following code.

```
- (SKSpriteNode *) randomGamePiece {
  NSArray *filename = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"piece1", @"piece2", @"piece3", nil];
  int r = arc4random () % [things count];

  NSString * randomFilename = [things objectAtIndex:r];
  SKSpriteNode *randomObject = [SKSpriteNode spriteWithImageNamed:randomFilename];

  return randomObject;
}
```

I wholeheartedly recommend browsing through the [Sprite Kit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/SpriteKit_PG.pdf) which contains many useful snippets and pointers for new and intermediate Sprite Kit programmers.